# sVARMA in R: different result with manual vs. built-in differencing

Tags: r, estimation, arima, data-transformation, vector-autoregression

```
z1=cbind(da[,1],da[,5])
dz1=diffM(z1,12)
m1a=sVARMA(z1,order=c(1,1,0),sorder=c(0,1,1),s=12,include.mean=F)
m1b=sVARMA(dz1,order=c(1,0,0),sorder=c(0,0,1),s=12,include.mean=F)
```

I think that there should be slight difference between `m1a` and `m1b` due to different initial values. Technically, there should be no difference using the original series and set `d=1` (`m1a`) and using differenced series and set `d=0`. However, the results are completely different. It looks like `m1b` is correct. I don't know why. I had the same problem for ARIMA and GARCH. 
At the end of the day, we need `m1a`. Usually, we are interested in predicting the original series, e.g. GDP not first-difference GDP.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left, otherwise you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

`z1` and `dz1` differ by *one* differencing operation, specifically a seasonal difference. Meanwhile, your model specifications in `m1a` and `m1b` differ by *two* differencing operations, one nonseasonal and one seasonal: you have orders (1,**1**,0)x(0,**1**,1) and (1,**0**,0)x(0,**0**,1).

To match the two, either difference `dz1` once more (non-seasonally) or try (1,**1**,0)x(0,**1**,1) and (1,**1**,0)x(0,**0**,1).